# Creation of simple formula with decimal and multiplication by other cell (by VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I have problem like in subject.
How can I create formula in `A1`  e.g. `= 3.14 * A2`

this code doesn't work and returns error
in final version myVal will be delivered by other function

```
Public Sub DecimalInFormulaTest()
   Dim myVal As Double
   myVal = 3.14
   ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=" & myVal & "*R1C2"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but it's a bit strange.
I tried use CStr() but it didn't work
just Str() is working OK

```
Public Sub DecimalInFormulaTest()
   Dim myVal As Double
   myVal = 3.14
   ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=" & Str(myVal) & "*R1C2"
End Sub
```

One more thing. I'm in region where decimal separator is comma not dot

Comment: or by FormulaLocal:  ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).FormulaLocal = "=" & CStr(myVal) & "*B1"

Comment: Or `FormulaR1C1Local`?

Answer (score 0):

This because `CStr` converts value with regard to specific locale. In some locales, decimal point is comma `,`, which is causing eventually an error, when trying to write it to formula.

This might be unexpected, because when writing in such locale formulas, you have to write them with comma as well, but it doesn't work like that in VBA. When you write formula with code, they have to be "english-specific", i.e. with english functions and dot as decimal separator.

So, `Str(num)` will return `3.14` if `num=3.14`, not `3,14` which solves your issue.

Quite longer solution, but better represents problem being solved:

```
Replace(CStr(3.14), ",", ".")
```